# Why does Arkansas relatively often fail to field major party candidates for US Senate elections?

Tags: united-states, election, senate, arkansas

In the 1966 US Senate election in Arkansas, the Democratic Party candidate won uncontested.

In 1990, the Democratic Party candidate won uncontested.

In 2008, no Republican Party candidate ran.

In 2020, the Democratic Party candidate dropped out in November 2019 after being the only Democrat to file.

Why does Arkansas relatively often fail to field major party candidates for US Senate elections?

Comment: This seems opinion-based both on the metrics you've chosen (are 4 elections out of... how many have they had? Hundreds? enough to qualify as "relatively often"?), but also on the possible reason why: people only run if they want to.

Comment: In Mississippi, there was no Democrat candidate in 1990 or 2002; since the Republican has won easily when it was contested in every race since the 1980s, presumably nobody was willing to spend the time and expense. Wikipedia has very detailed entries on all the Senate races so I'm sure you could find other states with similar situations.